# MATLAB: Elegant way to check if 'if' statement is NOT true

Tags: matlab, if-statement

I am writing a solution in which I need to check if an array contains any NaN values. If it does NOT, then I can go ahead and run a function on the data. This is my current solution:

```
if find(isnan(inputData))
% Nothing goes here since I only want the function to run if the 'if' statement fails
else
    doFunction(inputData);
end
```

Is there an elegant way of negating the 'if' statement; thus avoiding the empty first clause?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
if ~any(isnan(x(:)))
    doFunction(inputData);
end
```

Is that elegant enough for you ? If not, how do you like this ?

```
if all(isfinite(x(:)))
    doFunction(inputData);
end
```

Comment: That's great, thanks. But I still wonder is there a general way in MATLAB of checking immediately for the 'else' rather than the 'if'..?

Comment: @CaptainProg: The general way is to negate the condition in the if-statement. However, coding as you did in the OP can increase readability.

Comment: Whaddya mean ?  I thought you wanted to avoid an empty if clause and that's what you've got.